# Existence of a concave function passing through given points

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, machine-learning, interpolation, convex-geometry

I am wondering where to find proof or reference for the following fact:

Given variable sequence $\{ x_t \}_{t \in [T]} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and function value sequence $\{ y_t \}_{t \in [T]} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, when would it be possible to find a concave function $f$ such that $f(x_t) = y_t$?

I am aware that someone asked a question about the existence of a convex function that interpolates given gradients and values (https://mathoverflow.net/users/29697/usul), Existence of a strictly convex function interpolating given gradients and values, URL (version: 2019-04-13): https://mathoverflow.net/q/327940.

I originally thought my question is similar and trivial but realized that it actually needs some thinking. It's kind of like the machine learning problem, where we have some inputs and outputs and we want to find some "mapping" between them. However, here the additional requirement is that the "mapping" must be a concave function. Does there always exist such a concave function? Or maybe we need some additional constraints on the given $\{ x_t \}_{t \in [T]} $ and $\{ y_t \}_{t \in [T]} $ in order to guarantee the existence?

Comment: I general this is not possible. Note that if $x_s = \sum \lambda_t x_t$ is a convex combination of the $x_t$, then necessarily $y_s \geq \sum_t \lambda_t y_t$. Under this condition, I would guess that it is always possible. Also, do your $x_t$ live in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^d$?

Comment: What is the dimension of your variables? Are each of the $x_i$ scalars, or points in some higher-dimensional space?

Comment: Also, do you know the values of the $x_i$ in advance? Or are both the $x_i$ and $y_i$ unknown?

Comment: $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I've made it clear in my problem statement. $x_t$ and $y_t$ are known in advance, our goal is to build such a function $f(x)$ according to the given $x_t$ and $y_t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions can be found in Theorem 2 and Theorem 3 of

> G. Carlier, T. Lachand-Robert, and B. Maury. A numerical approach to variational problems subject to convexity constraint. Numerische Mathematik, 2001.